# Pass class style to MVC Razor C3 validation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Using MVC validation I do something like this to display error message

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.QuestionText)
```

That renders HTML

```
<span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="QuestionText">
<span class="" for="QuestionText" generated="true">Please fill in a question before Assigning it</span>
</span>
```

But I want to pass the style class as well, something like:

```
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.QuestionText, new {@class="notification error"})
```

But this does not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this;

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.QuestionText, null, new {@class="notification error"})
```